# How to use JSON data in rails and provide it to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, object, hash

I have a rails application where I have JSON data as shown below:

```
{"makes":[{"id":200347864,"name":"AM General","niceName":"am-general","models":[{"id":"AM_General_Hummer","name":"Hummer","niceName":"hummer","years":[{"id":3407,"year":1998},{"id":1140,"year":1999},{"id":305,"year":2000}]}]}]}
```

This is a very long list of car objects with multi-levels of nesting. Make, model, year, trim etc.

I want to send this JSON  to javascript and populate my autofill drop down menu.

Previously, I was using a third-party API and the code looked like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


    var prev ="https://xyz/makes";
    var rest ="?fmt=json&api_key=";
    var key = "<%= ENV['XYZ_API_KEY'] %>";
    var net = prev+rest+key;

    var options = [];
    options.push("All");
    var dictionary = {};

         $.ajax({

            url: net,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "get", 
            data: $(this).serialize()
         }).done(function(data){
            change_make(data);
            change_model();
         });




    function change_make(data) {

        for (var key in data["makes"]){
            if (data["makes"].hasOwnProperty(key)){

                var make = data["makes"][key];

                options.push(make.name);

                buffer = [];

                // console.log(make.models);

                for (var key2 in make.models){

                    // console.log(make.models[key2].name);

                    if (make.models.hasOwnProperty(key2)){

                        // console.log(make.models[key2].name);

                        buffer.push(make.models[key2].name);
                    }

                }


                dictionary[make.name] = buffer;

            }
        }

        dictionary["All"] = ["All"]

        // console.log(options);

        $.each(options, function(key, value) {   
             $('#category')
                 .append($("<option></option>")                            
                    .attr("value", value.html_safe)
                    .text(value));  
        });    

    };



    $('#category').on('change', function(){


        console.log("change success");

        change_model();



    });


    function change_model(){

        var make = $('#category').find(":selected").text();        
        var models = dictionary[make];
        // models.unshift("All");

        $('#subcategory').empty();

        $.each(models, function(key, value) {   
             $('#subcategory')                
                 .append($("<option></option>")                            
                    .attr("value",value.html_safe)
                    .text(value));  
        });
    }    

    $("#searchboxcontainer").delay(100).fadeIn(200);   


});
```

Instead of using the ajax request, I want to use json string directly. 
I wrote a helper method in application helper module as shown:

```
 def edmunds_json      
  the_json_object
 end
```

But when I am using it in javascript, its adding &gm characters and theobject comes out as:

`{:makes=&gt;[{:id=&gt;200347864, :name=&gt;&quot;AM General`",...

and the code is giving errors

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

When I am using escape in JSON, it's giving me the error on rails `unexpected $undefined. expecting ')`.

The JSON object is using double quotes and I want to use it in my code. How should I proceed so &gt etc won't be added.

Comment: did you try to parse the object using `JSON.parse` ?

Comment: Yes. But then it gave the error unexpected tIDENTIFIER "}". expected end

Comment: do you convert your data to json string from your backend before sending it to javascript function, using `.to_json` ?

Comment: No its an object available already. Beforehand I was using external API. Now I have the object available without a call to the database.

Comment: you mean you are not sending the data from your rails backend, what does the `edmunds_json` method do then?

Comment: It wraps the object into a callable method which I can use anywhere. It's not calling database. The object is already available.

Comment: yes, but where is that `edmunds_json` method being called?

Comment: i will replace the Ajax call with var data = <%= edmunds_json %>;

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need to do is to first convert your Ruby Hash into json in your helper

```
def edmunds_json      
  the_json_object.to_json
end code here
```

Then in your view in a script tag do something like this

```
<script>
  const object = <%= raw edmunds_json %>
  console.log(typeof(object)) // => Object
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using:

<%= get_make_model_json.to_s.gsub("=>",":").html_safe %>; in javascript

where get_make_model_json is:

```
def get_make_model_json      
      JSON.parse(
        '{
  "makes": [{
    "id": 200347864,
    "name": "AM General",
    "niceName": "am-general",
    "models": [{
      "id": "AM_General_Hummer",
      "name": "Hummer",
      "niceName": "hummer",
      "years": [{
        "id": 3407,
        "year": 1998
      }, {
        "id": 1140,
        "year": 1999
      }, {
        "id": 305,
        "year": 2000
      }]
    }]
  },...
end
```